# Confirming the mapping of $z\in\mathbb{C}$ under $\cos^2(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis

Goal: find the mapping of $S_0=\{z\in\mathbb{C},\; 0<\operatorname{Re}(z)<\pi/2\, \operatorname{Im}(z)>0\}$  under $\cos^2(z)$

I know that $w=\cos(z)$ would map every line with fixed $\operatorname{Re}(z)$ from the region into half hyperbola in $S_1=\{z\in \mathbb{C},\; \operatorname{Re}(z)>0,\; \operatorname{Im}(z)<0\}$. Then I consider $v = w^2, w=re^{i\theta}$. Hence it maps $S_1$ to $\{z\in\mathbb{C},\; \operatorname{Im}(z)<0\}$ as maximum $\theta$ doubles?

Just want to confirm my logic is correct. Thanks

Comment: We have $\operatorname {Im} \cos(x + i y) = -\sin x \sinh y$. Since $y$ changes from $-\infty$ to $\infty$, $\operatorname {Im} w$ is not always negative. Also consider where the boundary of $S_0$ is mapped to.

Comment: @Maxim sorry i forgot to add the condition that Im(z)>0 for S_0

Comment: If $f$ is analytic on an open containing $\overline{U}$ then (open mapping) the boundary of $f(U)$ is contained in $f(\partial U)$, if $f$ is injective then $f(\partial U)$ is a simple closed loop thus $f(\partial U)=\partial f(U)$ and $f(U)=Int(f(\partial U))$ and $f$ is biholomorphic $U\to Int(f(\partial U))$